# Shell Script to find the file and rename it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My goal is to create a shell script that will search for the file and rename it.

e.g. file `abc_123456789.csv` should name as `abc.csv`

to achieve this I have created the script like this.

```
find /abc/def -type f -name 'abc*' -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" $(echo $x | awk '{sub(/_.*/,"")'; print}')'
```

Could anyone please help me update the above script to remove the numbers from `abc_123456789.csv` and make it only `abc.csv`?

Comment: You open a single quote after `sh -c`. This single quote is closed after `awk`, which makes the string `{sub(/_.*/,"")` unquoted. The `(` in this string gives you the error. BTW, why fiddle with `find` and all the quoting issues, instead of using a loop?

Comment: As noted by @user1934428 it's a quoting issue. Instead of `sh` you could use `bash` and its pattern substitutions to simplify a lot: `bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%%_*}.csv"' bash {}`. Note also that in your case `-execdir` is probably a better choice than `-exec`. And if you have a lot of files to rename you could probably improve a bit the performance with a loop: `find /abc/def -type f -name 'abc*' -execdir bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do mv "$f" "${f%%_*}.csv"; done' bash {} +`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Wouldn't `${1%%_*}` work in `sh` as well? I think it is a POSIX expansion.

Comment: @user1934428: You're right, this works also with `sh`. I never remember what's POSIX and what's not, but I just checked and yes, it's POSIX.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet and user1934428 Thanks so much for your help, your solution works